# In-App purchase testing not returning product identifier

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase

I signed in to itunes connect and created my app by entering all informations and screenshots required. Currently the status is "Prepare for Submission"(Am I supposed to "submit for review" before I could test in-app purchase?). I went to the In-App Purchases section and added my in-app purchase with all the product id, apple id, type, and screenshot setup. The status is currently "Ready to Submit". I write the code to test in-app purchase, but the product identifier that I setup in itunes connect is not found. What did I do wrong?

Code for testing itunes connect:

```
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"-->my product identifier here<--" ];

    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [products firstObject]  : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't need to be "Submit for review".

You can test inapp purchase even if it's "Waiting for screenshot". There can be multiple reasons why it returns "invalid product". Is your product id the same as in itunes connect? Have you fulfilled ios paid app contract? Are bundle id's the same?

You can look to this checklist
http://www.gamedonia.com/game-development/solve-invalid-product-ids

Comment: I think the only thing I haven't done is fulfill the ios paid app contract. For the contract, everything is completed except for the part where I have to send apple the tax info. Do I have to wait until that's done before I could get in-app testing to work? If so, how long does it usually take?

Comment: Yes you have to wait :/. Hmm, in my case, for bank info processing lasts about 15min.

Comment: that gamedonia hyperlink is dead, BTW